# Angular - Can't set new HTTP Header

Tags: angular, apache, http

I'm trying to add an Authorization token to my request, but the header never get sent to the API,

[image]

```js
    public getIndicators(params: Object): Observable<any> {
        const data = {params : params};
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers.set('testHeader', 'test').set('test2', 'test3').set('Authorization', ' Bearer token');

        return this.http.post(API_URL + '/dashboard/getIndicators', data, {headers: headers});
    }
```

The same post request works on Postman if I put the headers in so I thought it could be because the app is served on localhost, so I added

```
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
```

in my apache2 conf and with this simple requests that do not require an Auth header does work

```js
    public login(formUsername: string, formPassword): Observable<any> {
    const data = {
      impersonate: formUsername,
      fmboPassword: formPassword
    };

    return this.httpClient.post<any>(API_URL + '/user/superlogin', data, { observe: 'response' });
  }
```

**Edit: A bit of clarification on the project architecture**

I'm running the angular app on my localhost:4200 and got my PHP (CodeIgniter ) api on a docker container (image php:7.2-apache) on port 80, I don't know what could block it.

This is the apache2 conf I set in my Dockerfile

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"

ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/sales-error.log"
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/sales-access.log" common

<Directory "/var/www/html/">
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted

    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"

</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should do the trick.

```
return this.httpClient.post<any>(API_URL + '/user/superlogin', data, { observe: response', headers: new HttpHeaders({'token': 'hello1 ' });
```

If you want this headers to be sent to server for each BE request you should use HttpInterceptor. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Comment: Unfortunetaly it does the same thing as what I had, I can see the 'token' in the Access-Control-Request-Headers but there is still no Authorization header when I print them in the back end

Comment: Is it possible that it gets lost somewhere in the middle? May be middlewere on serverside might be doing something?

Comment: That's what i'm looking into since there don't seem to be a problem with the angular part, but i'm not too sure what blocking the headers. I added a bit of infos on the architecturein the first post.